# Exit codes in Python

Tags: python, exit-code

I got a message saying `script xyz.py returned exit code 0`. What does this mean?

What do the exit codes in Python mean? How many are there? Which ones are important?

Comment: Where are you seeing this message?

Comment: @Jeremy 
At the bottom of PythonWin.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You're looking for calls to `sys.exit()` (`exit()` calls `sys.exit()`) in the script. The argument to that method is returned to the environment as the exit code.

It's fairly likely that the script is never calling the *exit* method, and that 0 is the default exit code.

Comment: Not sure at all. In Unix/Linux, the standard is: exit 0 in the case everything was ok. Type a command, then echo $?: if you read 0, it returned without an error. The idea is to have standard tests. If the code xyz.py did not encounter any error, it SHOULD return 0!

Comment: If you would like to change the exit code, prefer to exit cleanly using the exit builtin, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42719261/363437)

Comment: @vidstige: The `exit()` "built-in" (it's not actually a built-in all the time; e.g. it won't exist when Python is run with the `-S` switch) is the *wrong* solution; you want `sys.exit()` (which does in fact exit cleanly/consistently), not `exit()` (which is allowed to be replaced with weird things by tools, where `sys.exit` is generally supposed to stay untouched). The "unclean exit" function is `os._exit()`, which does terminate abruptly (it's used largely to kill workers in `fork`-based `multiprocessing` scenarios to avoid invoking cleanup that the parent process set up before the `fork`).

Answer (score 141):

From the documentation for [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> The optional argument arg can be an
> integer giving the exit status
> (defaulting to zero), or another type
> of object. If it is an integer, zero
> is considered “successful termination”
> and any nonzero value is considered
> “abnormal termination” by shells and
> the like. Most systems require it to
> be in the range 0-127, and produce
> undefined results otherwise. Some
> systems have a convention for
> assigning specific meanings to
> specific exit codes, but these are
> generally underdeveloped; Unix
> programs generally use 2 for command
> line syntax errors and 1 for all other
> kind of errors.

One example where exit codes are used are in shell scripts. In Bash you can check the special variable `$?` for the last exit status:

```
me@mini:~$ python -c ""; echo $?
0
me@mini:~$ python -c "import sys; sys.exit(0)"; echo $?
0
me@mini:~$ python -c "import sys; sys.exit(43)"; echo $?
43
```

Personally I try to use the exit codes I find in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h` (on a Linux system), but I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: From another post I found this link: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html  Might be usefull. :)

Comment: errno.h is typically for function call exit codes.  Attempts to standardize program exit codes have resulted in /usr/include/sysexits.h being present on most POSIX systems.

Comment: It's very good to know that "Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors"!

Comment: @dantiston **Concur.** Die-hard dyed-in-the-wool Gentoo advocate, yet I never knew that... until this fated day. (_My shame ends now._) Relatedly, note that `grep` breaks this trend by exiting with `1` when no lines match and `2` on actual errors. Thanks alot, Stallman.

Answer (score 55):

For the record, you can use POSIX standard exit codes defined [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-management).

Example:

```
import sys, os

try:
    config()
except:
    sys.exit(os.EX_CONFIG) 
try:
    do_stuff()
except:
    sys.exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE)
sys.exit(os.EX_OK) # code 0, all ok
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-management) these are only available on Unix operating systems so it is not fully portable.

Comment: If you'd like portable POSIX codes that are available on all operating systems, see the [`exitstatus`](https://pypi.org/project/exitstatus/) PyPI package.

Comment: The entirety of that package is 0 for success, and 1 for failure.

Comment: I thought you were kidding, Pavel. You were in fact not kidding: 
https://github.com/johnthagen/exitstatus/blob/master/exitstatus.py

Answer (score 24):

There is an [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html) module that defines standard exit codes:

For example, **Permission denied** is error code **13**:

```
import errno, sys

if can_access_resource():
    do_something()
else:
    sys.exit(errno.EACCES)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. These errno are not intended to be used as process exit codes. These are low level error codes intended to be used internally in programs, specifically those written in the C language. For Python, use exceptions whenever possible.

Comment: You're right. These are to be used internally. But you do not normally raise exceptions at the end user level. You use sys.exit(x) with x being an integer you choose arbitrarily. But you can use those begining with EX_ and defined in 'os' module. Like os.EX_OK or os.EX_IOERR

Comment: Sorry, but I’m also down-voting this because it’s misleading. Exit status codes and error numbers are _not_ interchangable/complementary. Using the given example, “permission denied” has an _error code_ of 13 (according to `errno` and [errno.h](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/errno.h#L51-L188)), but an _exit status code_ of 77 (according to `os` and [sysexits.h](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/include/sysexits.h#L96-L116)). Programs that emit the former are non-standard (_de facto vel jure_) and won’t play nicely with others that rightly expect the latter.

Answer (score 18):

Exit codes of 0 usually mean, "nothing wrong here."  However if the programmer of the script didn't follow convention you may have to consult the source to see what it means.  Usually a non-zero value is returned as an error code.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is "Depends on what exit code zero means".

However, in most cases, this means "Everything is Ok".

---

I like POSIX:

So, in the shell, I would type:

```
python script.py && echo 'OK' || echo 'Not OK'
```

If my Python script calls `sys.exit(0)`, the shell returns 'OK'

If my Python script calls `sys.exit(1)` (or any non-zero integer), the shell returns 'Not OK'.

It's your job to get clever with the shell, and read the documentation (or the source) for your script to see what the exit codes mean.

Comment: Just for completeness, 'Not OK' will be printed if Python script raised error OR had syntax error.

Answer (score 13):

Following [Unix exit codes](https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/) **0** - for success / OK, **1** - non success / error. You could simply use `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` call without importing `sys` module.

Comment: exit is intended for the interactive shell. sys.exit is intended for scripts. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501134/1144204

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to portably use the [standard POSIX exit codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html), see the [`exitstatus`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exitstatus/) package on PyPI.

Install the package:

```sh
$ pip install exitstatus
```

Use in your code:

```py
import sys
from exitstatus import ExitStatus

sys.exit(ExitStatus.success)
```

Answer (score 6):

The exit codes only have meaning as assigned by the script author. The Unix tradition is that exit code 0 means 'success', anything else is failure. The only way to be sure what the exit codes for a given script mean is to examine the script itself.

Answer (score 6):

Operating system commands have exit codes.  Look for [Linux exit codes](http://steve-parker.org/sh/exitcodes.shtml) to see some material on this.  The shell uses the exit codes to decide if the program worked, had problems, or failed.  There are some efforts to create standard (or at least commonly-used) exit codes.  See this [Advanced Shell Script](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) posting.

Answer (score 6):

> I recommend a clean shutdown with the exit(0) builtin rather than using sys.exit()

I'm not sure if this is good advice.

[The very documentation mentioned](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) reads:

> The site module (which is imported automatically during startup, except if the -S command-line option is given) adds several constants to the built-in namespace. They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and **should not be used in programs**.

Then:

> exit(code=None)
>
> Objects that when printed, print a message like “Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit”, and when called, raise SystemExit with the specified exit code.

If we compare it to [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) documentation, it's using the same mechanism which is raising a `SystemExit` exception.

Answer (score 3):

Exit codes in many programming languages are up to programmers. So you have to look at your program source code (or manual). Zero usually means "everything went fine".

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND:
To face the bug in gitlab-ci (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27668), I simply generated a file with the error code:

Python part:

```
with open("error_code.log", 'w') as file:
   file.write('2') # this will trigger a warning
```

and then in the yml file:

```
.step_name:
  variables:
    # my vars
  script:
    - python my_code.py arg1 arg2
    - exit `cat error_code.log`
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes:
      - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To Exit anywhere from python code you can right `sys.exit()`

This is called making normal termination, Use cases:
a) Wrong password
b) Wrong API Key
c) Exception occurred, etc.

Code sample:

`import sys; sys.exit()`

Comment: Hello, this is a duplicated answer to the most upvoted one. Please only submit unique answers.

Answer (score 0):

`script program.py returned error code 0` means that **program.py doesn't have any errors**. Input the error code into `os.strerror()` to see its corresponding error. Of course, on `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.GET` and `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.POST`, the successful request code is `200`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Program exit codes have no direct relationship to HTTP response codes.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I'm just giving a heads-up to everyone who sees this.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we have the [`errno` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html), which defines the exit code numbers you must use in your Python projects. As said in the documentation, they were borrowed from the C/C++ programming languages, which define the exit code numbers in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` and `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h` on GNU/Linux systems. It follows the meaning of each exit code:

- `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`

  ```c
  /* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
  #ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H
  #define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H

  #define EPERM        1  /* Operation not permitted */
  #define ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
  #define ESRCH        3  /* No such process */
  #define EINTR        4  /* Interrupted system call */
  #define EIO      5  /* I/O error */
  #define ENXIO        6  /* No such device or address */
  #define E2BIG        7  /* Argument list too long */
  #define ENOEXEC      8  /* Exec format error */
  #define EBADF        9  /* Bad file number */
  #define ECHILD      10  /* No child processes */
  #define EAGAIN      11  /* Try again */
  #define ENOMEM      12  /* Out of memory */
  #define EACCES      13  /* Permission denied */
  #define EFAULT      14  /* Bad address */
  #define ENOTBLK     15  /* Block device required */
  #define EBUSY       16  /* Device or resource busy */
  #define EEXIST      17  /* File exists */
  #define EXDEV       18  /* Cross-device link */
  #define ENODEV      19  /* No such device */
  #define ENOTDIR     20  /* Not a directory */
  #define EISDIR      21  /* Is a directory */
  #define EINVAL      22  /* Invalid argument */
  #define ENFILE      23  /* File table overflow */
  #define EMFILE      24  /* Too many open files */
  #define ENOTTY      25  /* Not a typewriter */
  #define ETXTBSY     26  /* Text file busy */
  #define EFBIG       27  /* File too large */
  #define ENOSPC      28  /* No space left on device */
  #define ESPIPE      29  /* Illegal seek */
  #define EROFS       30  /* Read-only file system */
  #define EMLINK      31  /* Too many links */
  #define EPIPE       32  /* Broken pipe */
  #define EDOM        33  /* Math argument out of domain of func */
  #define ERANGE      34  /* Math result not representable */

  #endif
  ```
- `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`

  ```c
  /* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
  #ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H
  #define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H

  #include <asm-generic/errno-base.h>

  #define EDEADLK     35  /* Resource deadlock would occur */
  #define ENAMETOOLONG    36  /* File name too long */
  #define ENOLCK      37  /* No record locks available */

  /*
  * This error code is special: arch syscall entry code will return
  * -ENOSYS if users try to call a syscall that doesn't exist.  To keep
  * failures of syscalls that really do exist distinguishable from
  * failures due to attempts to use a nonexistent syscall, syscall
  * implementations should refrain from returning -ENOSYS.
  */
  #define ENOSYS      38  /* Invalid system call number */

  #define ENOTEMPTY   39  /* Directory not empty */
  #define ELOOP       40  /* Too many symbolic links encountered */
  #define EWOULDBLOCK EAGAIN  /* Operation would block */
  #define ENOMSG      42  /* No message of desired type */
  #define EIDRM       43  /* Identifier removed */
  #define ECHRNG      44  /* Channel number out of range */
  #define EL2NSYNC    45  /* Level 2 not synchronized */
  #define EL3HLT      46  /* Level 3 halted */
  #define EL3RST      47  /* Level 3 reset */
  #define ELNRNG      48  /* Link number out of range */
  #define EUNATCH     49  /* Protocol driver not attached */
  #define ENOCSI      50  /* No CSI structure available */
  #define EL2HLT      51  /* Level 2 halted */
  #define EBADE       52  /* Invalid exchange */
  #define EBADR       53  /* Invalid request descriptor */
  #define EXFULL      54  /* Exchange full */
  #define ENOANO      55  /* No anode */
  #define EBADRQC     56  /* Invalid request code */
  #define EBADSLT     57  /* Invalid slot */

  #define EDEADLOCK   EDEADLK

  #define EBFONT      59  /* Bad font file format */
  #define ENOSTR      60  /* Device not a stream */
  #define ENODATA     61  /* No data available */
  #define ETIME       62  /* Timer expired */
  #define ENOSR       63  /* Out of streams resources */
  #define ENONET      64  /* Machine is not on the network */
  #define ENOPKG      65  /* Package not installed */
  #define EREMOTE     66  /* Object is remote */
  #define ENOLINK     67  /* Link has been severed */
  #define EADV        68  /* Advertise error */
  #define ESRMNT      69  /* Srmount error */
  #define ECOMM       70  /* Communication error on send */
  #define EPROTO      71  /* Protocol error */
  #define EMULTIHOP   72  /* Multihop attempted */
  #define EDOTDOT     73  /* RFS specific error */
  #define EBADMSG     74  /* Not a data message */
  #define EOVERFLOW   75  /* Value too large for defined data type */
  #define ENOTUNIQ    76  /* Name not unique on network */
  #define EBADFD      77  /* File descriptor in bad state */
  #define EREMCHG     78  /* Remote address changed */
  #define ELIBACC     79  /* Can not access a needed shared library */
  #define ELIBBAD     80  /* Accessing a corrupted shared library */
  #define ELIBSCN     81  /* .lib section in a.out corrupted */
  #define ELIBMAX     82  /* Attempting to link in too many shared libraries */
  #define ELIBEXEC    83  /* Cannot exec a shared library directly */
  #define EILSEQ      84  /* Illegal byte sequence */
  #define ERESTART    85  /* Interrupted system call should be restarted */
  #define ESTRPIPE    86  /* Streams pipe error */
  #define EUSERS      87  /* Too many users */
  #define ENOTSOCK    88  /* Socket operation on non-socket */
  #define EDESTADDRREQ    89  /* Destination address required */
  #define EMSGSIZE    90  /* Message too long */
  #define EPROTOTYPE  91  /* Protocol wrong type for socket */
  #define ENOPROTOOPT 92  /* Protocol not available */
  #define EPROTONOSUPPORT 93  /* Protocol not supported */
  #define ESOCKTNOSUPPORT 94  /* Socket type not supported */
  #define EOPNOTSUPP  95  /* Operation not supported on transport endpoint */
  #define EPFNOSUPPORT    96  /* Protocol family not supported */
  #define EAFNOSUPPORT    97  /* Address family not supported by protocol */
  #define EADDRINUSE  98  /* Address already in use */
  #define EADDRNOTAVAIL   99  /* Cannot assign requested address */
  #define ENETDOWN    100 /* Network is down */
  #define ENETUNREACH 101 /* Network is unreachable */
  #define ENETRESET   102 /* Network dropped connection because of reset */
  #define ECONNABORTED    103 /* Software caused connection abort */
  #define ECONNRESET  104 /* Connection reset by peer */
  #define ENOBUFS     105 /* No buffer space available */
  #define EISCONN     106 /* Transport endpoint is already connected */
  #define ENOTCONN    107 /* Transport endpoint is not connected */
  #define ESHUTDOWN   108 /* Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown */
  #define ETOOMANYREFS    109 /* Too many references: cannot splice */
  #define ETIMEDOUT   110 /* Connection timed out */
  #define ECONNREFUSED    111 /* Connection refused */
  #define EHOSTDOWN   112 /* Host is down */
  #define EHOSTUNREACH    113 /* No route to host */
  #define EALREADY    114 /* Operation already in progress */
  #define EINPROGRESS 115 /* Operation now in progress */
  #define ESTALE      116 /* Stale file handle */
  #define EUCLEAN     117 /* Structure needs cleaning */
  #define ENOTNAM     118 /* Not a XENIX named type file */
  #define ENAVAIL     119 /* No XENIX semaphores available */
  #define EISNAM      120 /* Is a named type file */
  #define EREMOTEIO   121 /* Remote I/O error */
  #define EDQUOT      122 /* Quota exceeded */

  #define ENOMEDIUM   123 /* No medium found */
  #define EMEDIUMTYPE 124 /* Wrong medium type */
  #define ECANCELED   125 /* Operation Canceled */
  #define ENOKEY      126 /* Required key not available */
  #define EKEYEXPIRED 127 /* Key has expired */
  #define EKEYREVOKED 128 /* Key has been revoked */
  #define EKEYREJECTED    129 /* Key was rejected by service */

  /* for robust mutexes */
  #define EOWNERDEAD  130 /* Owner died */
  #define ENOTRECOVERABLE 131 /* State not recoverable */

  #define ERFKILL     132 /* Operation not possible due to RF-kill */

  #define EHWPOISON   133 /* Memory page has hardware error */

  #endif
  ```

Note that the exit error codes defined in `errno` has the same name as the C/C++ exit error codes.

Answer (score -3):

To allow exception handlers and other things execute I recommend a clean shutdown with the [`exit(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) builtin rather than using `sys.exit()` which terminates the process abruptly.

Comment: So what;s the difference? Where does this information come from? Do you mean the execution of the "at exit" handlers or what exactly are you referring to? `SystemExit` appears to get raised either way.

Comment: mm, I confused it with `os._exit`, the both seems to raise `SystemExit`.

Comment: Wrong: `sys.exit()` **does** shutdown cleanly, just like `exit()`. They both do the _same_ thing: raise a `SystemExit` exception. Actually, `exit()` is meant for the interactive sessions, not scripts, so conceptually `sys.exit()` *is* the indicated one. You might be confusing with `os._exit()`, that's the one that terminates abruptly.

Comment: Adding to @MestreLion: `exit()` isn't even a true built-in; [it's jammed into the built-ins after the fact when the `site` module is imported](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module). This happens implicitly most of the time, but for Python scripts that are trying to run quickly, and don't rely on third-party modules (installed in `site-packages`), they can be run with the `-S` switch to disable import of `site` entirely, and `exit()` won't exist (`sys.exit()` still will).

Comment: Ah, yes. I was confusing it with `os._exit`