# Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python

Tags: python, exit

In Python, there are two similarly-named functions, `exit()` and `sys.exit()`. What's the difference and when should I use one over the other?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering in light of the passing of return codes, both will correctly have python emit the expected return code.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747371/4014959

Answer (score 602, accepted):

[`exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#exit) is a helper for the interactive shell - [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is intended for use in programs.

> The [`site`](https://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site) module (which is imported automatically during startup, except if the [`-S`](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S) command-line option is given) adds several constants to the built-in namespace *(e.g. `exit`)*. **They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs**.

---

Technically, they do mostly the same: raising [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit). `sys.exit` does so in [*sysmodule.c*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06fe77a84bd29d51506ab2ff703ae585a6121af2/Python/sysmodule.c#L337-L346):

```c
static PyObject *
sys_exit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *exit_code = 0;
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "exit", 0, 1, &exit_code))
        return NULL;
    /* Raise SystemExit so callers may catch it or clean up. */
    PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_SystemExit, exit_code);
   return NULL;
}
```

While `exit` is defined in [site.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06fe77a84bd29d51506ab2ff703ae585a6121af2/Lib/site.py#L365-L366) and [_sitebuiltins.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06fe77a84bd29d51506ab2ff703ae585a6121af2/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L13-L26), respectively.

```
class Quitter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Use %s() or %s to exit' % (self.name, eof)
    def __call__(self, code=None):
        # Shells like IDLE catch the SystemExit, but listen when their
        # stdin wrapper is closed.
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
        except:
            pass
        raise SystemExit(code)
__builtin__.quit = Quitter('quit')
__builtin__.exit = Quitter('exit')
```

---

Note that there is a third exit option, namely [os._exit](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit), which exits without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc. (and which  should normally only be used in the child process after a `fork()`).

Comment: I suspect that exit(main()) is a common idiom because people don't pick up on the *should not be used in programs* note.  It works fine unless [`-S`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S) is used.  A way to make it work even with `-S` is to specify `from sys import *`.

Comment: @nobar, true, but then you do not really want to use `from module import *`.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev, I'm not sure what you are asking exactly? It might be an interesting question on its own.

Comment: It would be a nice add to this answer to see what issues if any are there for using any of the three exit functions within a "with statement."

Answer (score 58):

If I use `exit()` in a code and run it in the shell, it shows a message asking whether I want to kill the program or not. It's really disturbing.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJfr.jpg)

But `sys.exit()` is better in this case. It closes the program and doesn't create any dialogue box.

Comment: This is because it is designed for use in the interactive shell. So even if you want the dialog, `sys.exit()` should be used inside programs.

Answer (score 13):

## Solution, Origins, Differences & Speed

### Why do we need the [`exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html) /
[`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) commands?

Usually, the code runs through the lines until the end and the program exits automatically.
Occasionally, we would like to ask the program to close before the full cycle run.
An example case is when you implement authentication and a user fails to authenticate, in some cases you would like to exit the program.

### The `exit()`

Exits Python.

Maybe you didn't know this, but it's a synonym of `quit()` and was added after `quit()` to make python more user friendly.
Designed to work with interactive shells.

**Usage:**
Use the built-in `exit()` out of the box, as is, without importing any library.
Just type this:

```
exit()
```

Execution Time: **0.03s**

**Pros:**

- Faster to use (built-in)
- Works both with python 2.x and python 3.x
- Fast
- Can be used exactly like `sys.exit()` (with the exception)

**Cons:**

- No exception message

### The `sys.exit()`

Exits Python and raising the SystemExit exception (requires an import).
Designed to work inside programs.

**Usage:**

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Execution Time (of just the import and `sys.exit()`): **0.07s**

Or you can use a message for the SystemExit exception:

*Added [`finally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block to illustrate code cleanup clause. Inspired by @Nairum.*

```
import sys
try:
  sys.exit("This is an exit!")
except SystemExit as error:
  print(error)
finally:
  print("Preforming cleanup in 3, 2, 1..")
  # Do code cleanup on exit
```

Output:

> This is an exit!
>
> Preforming cleanup in 3, 2, 1..

**Pros:**

- Triggers SystemExit exception
- You can use an exception message
- Closes without a dialog
- Utilizes `finally` clause of `try`
- Works both with python 2.x and python 3.x

**Cons:**

- Needs an import
- Slower by 57.1% than `exit()`

### Conclusion:

If you don't need an exception with an optional message, then use `exit()`, this is faster and built-in.
If you require more functionality of an exception with an optional message, use `sys.exit()`.

*In the code examples I am using Python 3.x*

Comment: I write something strange. Cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try statements are honored by `exit()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: Thank you, @Nairum.
I have added an example to your reference to the answer.

Comment: This answer is wrong on so many levels. First of all, `exit()` also raises `SystemExit`. Second,  your performance comparison is unfair. You should not include the import time unless you never use the `sys` module anywhere else in your code, which is unlikely (other modules may import it too). Without considering the import time, the performance is reversed. Also, as @miku's answer says, you should not use `exit()` in scripts just because it's shorter, it's only meant to be used in the REPL. For more details: https://gist.github.com/nyuszika7h/f2a5962995ed1adb403d7d27b3e7950e