# how to exit a python script in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.2 and trying to exit it after the user inputs that they don't want to continue, is there code that will exit it in an if statement inside a while loop? I've already tried using `exit()`, `sys.exit()`, `sys.quit()`, `quit()`, and raise `SystemExit`.

Comment: all those should work?

Comment: `if True: exit()` works.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using where this doesn't work? Are you trying to exit the program, or just the `if` statement? Are you catching SystemExit for some reason?

Comment: Does your code ever fulfil the if condition the exit statement is in?

Comment: The only cases in which this could possibly fail are (a) not actually calling `exit`, (b) catching `SystemExit` or `BaseException`, (c) multithreading or multiprocessing, (d) really funky signal handling, or (e) embedded/custom Python interpreter. I strongly suspect it's (a). But if you don't give us your code (or, better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that minimally shows the same problem), we can't do more than suspect and guess.

Comment: im trying to exit the whole script, the code is:                       (newline)if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
(newline)        print("ok, carry on then")
(newline)    elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
(newline)        print("ok, sayonnara")
(newline)        sys.exit()

Comment: @ethan: It is impossible to format code in comments on SO. That makes it very hard to read (and also makes it impossible to diagnose indentation errors). Just edit your question and paste the properly-formatted code there. Also, please describe the actual input/output sequence that you're seeing. (For example, if you type "N", see "ok, sayonnara", but then don't exit, tell us exactly that.)

Comment: all of the things you tried will work but if youre running the code in the IDE they will just give an error but if you run it from the cmd it will exit it could be something else in youre code

Comment: @ethan post your code in the question body.

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: First, at least some of them won't work anywhere (there's no such thing as `sys.quit()`. Second, I don't know what IDE you use, but in IDLE, Eclipse/PyDev, and both of the major emacs modes, if your program exits normally the IDE doesn't give an error.

Comment: @abarnert sorry tryed to write IDLE it just raises a exit i mean what im saying is in IDLE it wont actually close the window it will stop the program sorry

Comment: this is becoming way more difficult than it needs to be just post youre code in the question im sure one of us can easily help!!

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: I understand your frustration, but really, there's no harm here to anyone but the OP himself. If he never edits the question to become answerable, it'll just be closed (either in the present, or months later when someone searches for the same problem and finds a dead and useless question).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/73663/3345375

Answer (score 48):

This works fine for me:

```
while True:
   answer = input('Do you want to continue?:')
   if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
      print("ok, carry on then")
   elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
      print("sayonara, Robocop")
      exit()
```

edit: use `input` in python 3.2 instead of `raw_input`

Comment: already set up something similar and it didn't work. this is the code.       if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
                print("ok, carry on then")
            elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
                print("ok, sayonnara")
                sys.exit()

Comment: @ethan This solution is fair good enough. Paste your exact code here.

Comment: I typed your code almost verbatim into my python interpreter and it worked fine. You should post your code. Maybe something else going on in your while loop?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: The OP said that doesn't work, so why would they accept it?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this actually works for you in Python 3.2. When I try it, I get the expected `NameError`.

Comment: @abarnert change `raw_input` into `input` and it works fine. Is it what you meant?

Comment: yeah, thanks for pointing that out. Regardless of the mechanism for getting the input, the point is that the exit() function ends the program when the if statement is properly tested.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that your code works because it's so easy and so correct :) @abarnert - any problems with this code?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Yes, I'm nearly 100% sure this code works. Sadly, I'm also 95% sure that it's not the OP's code (even though he implied that it was), or he wouldn't have had this question in the first place…

Comment: It's recommended to use `import sys` and then `sys.exit()` instead of the built-in `exit()`. See [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit) and [Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6501121/3345375).

Comment: name 'exit' is not defined