# Python - How do you exit a program if a condition is met?

Tags: python

I can't exit the program when the condition at start of the code is met and it also prevents the rest of the code from working when it is not met. However if you remove the conditions from the start the code works fine. How do I get the conditions at the start to work properly? P.S I know the code can be condensed.

```
import sys  
user1 = (input("User 1 type your name " )).lower
user2 = (input("User 2 type your name ")).lower
if user1 != "bob":
    sys.exit()
if user2 != "fred":
    sys.exit()

from random import randint
total = 1
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
while total <6:
    roll = (input("User 1 x press 1 to roll the dice "))
    if roll == "x":
        dice = randint(1,6)
        print("You got",dice)
        score1 = score1+dice
        print("User 1 your score is",score1)

    roll2 = (input("\nUser 2 press x to roll the dice "))
    if roll2 == "x":
        dice = randint(1,6)
        print("You got",dice)
        score2 = score2+dice
        print("User 2 your score is",score2)

    total = total+1
    if total == 6:
        print("\nUser1 your total score is",score1)
        print("User2 your total score is",score2)

while total >= 6:
    if score1 == score2:
        print("It's a tie! Whoever rolls the highest number wins")
        roll = (input("User 1 press x to roll the dice"))
        if roll == "x":
            dice = randint(1,6)
            print("You got",dice)
            score1 = score1+dice
            print("User 1 your score is",score1)

        roll2 = (input("\nUser 2 press x to roll the dice"))
        if roll2 == "x":
            dice = randint(1,6)
            print("You got",dice)
            score2 = score2+dice
            print("User 2 your score is",score2)

    if score1 > score2:
        print("\nUser 1 wins")
        break
    if score1 < score2:
        print("\nUser 2 wins")
        break
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want the conditions to do, and what they are currently doing?

Comment: lower is a method, you need to call it

Comment: What are those "conditions at the start"? The two `if user..` sections?

Comment: This was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179615/how-to-exit-a-python-script-in-an-if-statement

Comment: you need to *call* the string methods, using parentheses: `user1 = (input("User 1 type your name " )).lower()`

Comment: @DanielRoseman nailed it, you forgot the parentheses on `.lower()` which means  it will never equal a string

Comment: In the future, you should *really* do some basic debugging. You probably could have discovered this yourself with a couple of `print`s

Comment: `sys.exit()` will force immediate exit of the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lower` is actually a method,  and you have to call it. Instead of writing `.lower` try writing `.lower()`