# How do I quit my game by typing in 'quit'?

Tags: python, quit

```
#Word Jumble Game

import random
import string

def jumbled():
words = ['Jumble', 'Star']#, 'Candy', 'Wings', 'Power', 'String', 'Shopping', 'Blonde', 'Steak', 'Speakers', 'Case', 'Stubborn', 'Cat', 'Marker', 'Elevator', 'Taxi', 'Eight', 'Tomato', 'Penguin', 'Custard']
count = 0    
loop = True
loop2 = True
while loop:
word = string.lower(random.choice(words)
jumble = list(word)
random.shuffle(jumble)
scrambled = "".join(jumble) 
while loop2:
    print '\n',scrambled,'\n'
    guess = raw_input('Guess the word: ')
    quit = set(['quit','Quit'])
    choice = 'quit'
    if guess.lower() == word:    
        print '\nCorrect!'
        count+=1
        print "You took",count,"trie(s) in order to get the right answer",jumbled()
    else:
        print '\nTry again!\n'
        count+=1
        if count == 3:
            if words[0]*2:
                print "It looks like you're having trouble!"
                print 'Your hint is: %s'(words) # I'm trying to pull a word from the above list here.



jumbled()
```

Hi there! How do I go about quitting the game whenever I type in 'quit' or 'Quit'?

Basically I've created a program that gives you a mixed, jumbled up word, then I'll have to guess it correctly. When I get the ability to type, I'd like to type quit so I can exit the game whenever necessary.

Thanks in advance! (You don't need to know how the game works, I just need to find a way to type in quit then the game will quit)

Also, where would I type in the code to make it quit? Please explain this also if you're just giving me the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
guess = raw_input('Guess the word: ')
if guess in ['quit','Quit']:
    print "Goodbye!"
    sys.exit()
```

See also: [Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python)

Comment: why note `guess.trim().lower() = 'quit'` since QUIT quIT qUiT QUIT QUit...etc should all be valid.  Or even `guess.trim().lower() in ['q', 'quit']`

Comment: We could also add: stop, exit, bye, goodbye, f***off, die, ^D, i need to go now, for the love of GOD QUIT ALREADY, etc. so between the set test and your suggestion, I think its covered.

Comment: After I type quit, it keeps looping around to the next jumbled word?

Comment: Does it also print "Goodbye!" ?

Comment: The block here goes inside the loop2 using your existing guess=raw_input line, except the import which goes at the top.

Comment: Nevermind! Instead of sys.exit, I used loop = False and it quits the loop and stops the program! Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Yeah well `sys.exit()` will work, `sys.exit` won't.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `elif` condition.

```
import sys
# ...

if guess.lower() == word:    
    print '\nCorrect!'
    # ...
elif guess.lower() == 'quit':
    sys.exit()    
else:
    print '\nTry again!\n'
    # ...
```