# Loop contining not working?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code I am a new to Python, it repeats even if you Type "Y" and it doesn't exit the program when typing "N". Thanks in Advance, forgive my indentation errors 
if I type in Y it just repeats the code/ question when using Break and when typing in N the code ends but the program doesn't exit:

```
while True:
    answer = input("Would You Like To Play?")
    if answer == "Y":
        print("good luck")
    elif answer == "N":
        exit()
```

Comment: _"forgive my errors"_. If you mean, forgive the incorrect indentation, I'd prefer you just fix it rather than leave it broken and apologize about it. Meet us halfway please.

Comment: Tell us the exact error please.

Comment: What are you expecting your code to do when the answer is "Y" and "N" respectively?

Comment: For your "N" part you should use sys.exit() Read this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python

Comment: if a user types "y" in it should continue the rest of the code which carries on to asking the users name but if the user types "N" the program should end

Comment: Thank you all for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the loop, with `while True:` it will always indefinitely execute unless you exit the loop with a `break` or an `exit()`.

A better practice however, is using a Boolean value as a loop control variable and changing it when you need to. That will break the loop.

This will work :

```
flag = True
while flag:
    answer = input("Would You Like To Play?")
    if answer == "Y" or answer == "y":
        print("good luck")
        #do whatever you want to here
        flag = False 
    elif answer == "N" or answer =="n":
        flag = False
```

Also in your code the indentation was wrong, I edited it so it's alright now, check your indentation because indentation matters a lot in terms of control flow. That might fix it.

Comment: thank you for your code however when typing "Y" it just repeats the  question

Comment: because you had while at the start, you have to escape the loop, either by `break` or exit(), using a flag is a better control structure, since you have `while True:` it will always loop indefinitely until you manually break the loop. Using flags is better here as I changed the answer to reflect.