# How should a distutils `Command` return a non-zero exit code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the simplest possible `python setup.py cmd`:

```
from distutils.core import Command, setup


class Foo(Command):
    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass

setup(
    cmdclass={'cmd': Foo}
)
```

It does precisely nothing.

But suppose something goes wrong while we're doing nothing, how should the command return a non-zero exit code to the user?

Return values seem to be ignored; [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.cmd.Command.run) says only:

> All terminal output and filesystem interaction should be done by run().

which seems relevant without being particularly helpful.

Perhaps we should infer to `exit`:

```
class Foo(Command):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        exit(1)
```

This works, of course.

But it's not clear to me that it's the right thing to do: if the command is run as a part of a longer process, or it's overriding a built-in command, presumably nothing further will execute.

We could raise a relevant exception directly instead, assuming it might be more likely to be well-handled, but then there's a nasty traceback when we exit - what if we've already logged something nicer ourselves?

```
class Foo(Command):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        print('Oh noes!', file=sys.stderr)
        exit(1)
```

Is this safe to do; is there a better alternative?

Comment: Raise an exception?  BTW `exit()` should not be used programatically, `sys.exit()` is preferred.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python

Comment: @cdarke Huh, that's odd one (I mean, why not `print` and `sys.print` then..), cheers. I considered raising an exception, but as noted in my OP, the traceback might not be (I would go so far as "probably isn't") desired.

Comment: It is an oddball, it is not obvious and you are certainly not the only person using it.  But its not `sys`, its `__builtins__.print('hello')` (for python 3).

Comment: @cdarke Right, but it's also `__builtins__.exit` - I just meant it's odd to have different function to call interactively. Especially considering that each option works under each circumstance anyway!

Answer (score 1):

While exit will defintely work, raising any of the [`distutils.errors`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.errors) with the error message desired to halt execution is how distutils handle problems internally.  For instance, if one wish to prevent editable (develop) installation method provided by setuptools, using only `distutils` API, raising `DistutilsError` can be achieve this.

```
from setuptools.command.develop import develop 
from distutils.errors import DistutilsError

class fail_develop(develop):

    def run(self):
        raise DistutilsError('develop installation mode unsupported')

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'develop': fail_develop},
)
```

Running that with the develop option may result in this:

```
running develop
error: develop installation mode unsupported
```

Execution will halt, as that is trapped and a `SystemExit` will be raised (now if somehow the whole process is wrapped by some other Python libraries that trap all exceptions including `SystemExit` or some other process expect a non-zero exit code, a traceback or other unexpected output will likely be produced).  While on the surface this is not too different than raising `SystemExit` (or calling `sys.exit`) directly, there are prefixes that do get generated for errors such as `DistutilsSetupError` that one might raise in a custom `Distribution` class.  So with all that said, calling `sys.exit` is fine.