# Get exit status code from Python, e.g. 0 or 1

Tags: shell, exit

I have a Python script which will do some actions, and depending on the result, will exit with a code 0 (all right) or 1 (not good).

I want to catch this result, store it into a variable and send it over UDP. This cannot be done inside the Python script (requirement).

So let's say my script is something like:

```
import sys
# Do some stuff
sys.exit(0) # or sys.exit(1)
```

Which I run with `python script.py`.

How can I get this exit status code (0 or 1)?

I try to echo `$errorlevel`, but it only prints a blank line. I also try to use `exit(0)` instead of `sys.exit()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python)) and some other unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: `sys.exit(0)` is the correct way to send the return code to your shell. But you didn't say which OS or shell you're using. In bash & similar shells, `$?` has the exit code of the last command.

Comment: "Which I run with python *script.sh**.", didn't you mean "Which I run with python script.py"?

Comment: Yes, sorry with .py

Comment: Is this actually a question about Python? As far as I can tell you're asking how to capture the exit code of a process (it's Python in this case) - but it could be any process. As @PM2Ring mentions - this is dependant upon your shell/environment etc...

Comment: @PM2Ring I am running MacOS.

Comment: This shoud work on Posix: `python -c "import sys; sys.exit(1)"; echo $?`=> 1

Comment: This is not a question on python per se. it is a question about your shell. Which one do you use? Bash, sh, fish, ...? in bash you capture the last exit code with `$?`. How are you sending the captured variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since as per your answer you are using `zsh`

test.py

```
import sys
sys.exit(12)
```

in your console

```
python test.py
RC=$?
echo "Exit code $RC"
program_to_send $RC
```

Comment: I dont quite see the idea of line 2 and 3 - why not just echo $? directly?

Comment: @Jakob `echo` would set it's own exit code and the second call would use that instead of the original one. So to make both consistent I store the return and use it in both places.

Comment: when I do it (without  the RC=$?), it returns the correct values - 0 if everything is fine, but when I force an error in the .py file, it returns 1

Comment: @Jakob Please post a new question so we can discuss it properly there.

Answer (score 3):

It's a script question, not a Python question, but in the Bash shell you use `$?` and since any command changes `$?`, it's usually a good idea to save a copy.

```
python script.py
RC=$?

echo $RC
[ $RC == 0 ] && echo Success || echo Failed
# Replace above lines by whatever you need to send $RC via UDP ...
```

<sub>If it's a Windows CMD script question, you should probably repost with the appropriate tags. (I don't do Windows any more, thank <deity>.)</sub>

Comment: If one uses `shell` than last line should be change to  `[ $RC==0 ] && ...`.

Answer (score -2):

This should be done the right way by catching exceptions and using logger.

```
import logging, time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='/path/to/file/errorlog.log')

try:
    #MySQL Connection
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    errortime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    logging.exception(errortime)
    raise os._exit(0)
```