# Is it better to exit a python script from within a function or from main?

Tags: python

Apologies if this is the wrong way to ask this question.

So I did some basic google searches and looked at the [PEP-8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), but I still can't find a good code guide for my question:

Is it better to exit my python script from within a function or to `return 1` and let the `__main__` body handle exiting?

Example:

```
def exit_fun():
  if foo:
    keep going
  else:
    exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  exit_fun()
  next_fun()
```

-or-

```
def exit_fun():
  if foo:
    keep going
  else:
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
  funfun = exit_fun()
  if funfun == 1:
    exit(1)
  next_fun()
```

The frist way looks cleaner to my eyes but my eyes don't compare to a style guide.

Comment: Why is the script exiting? Is that error handling? I'd find that jarring for a script to suddenly exit in the middle of execution. Rather I'd find it more canonical to `raise` a specific exception or use error codes.

Comment: Note that `exit(1)` is basically just `raise SystemExit(1)`.

Comment: @CoryKramer: It's not unusual for a script to exit if it encounters an error. If you don't need any more error handling in your program than that, there's no need for exceptions or error codes (although `exit()` technically raises an exception).

Comment: It _is_ better style for everything to return to `main` and let it handle exiting. BTW, the plain `exit` function is a bit odd. It's ok to use it in the interactive interpreter, but it's safer to use `sys.exit` in a proper script, or just `raise SystemExit`, as suggested by Dietrich Epp. Please see [Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501134/4014959).

Comment: @CoryKramer sorry to omit that, it isn't error handling as such (I'd used try/except stanzas for that) but more of a 'Does a prerequisite exist?' aka does an external script I'm calling exist on my system.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks!  I'm a python newb and I'm trying to make my code as stylishly correct as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As PM2Ring wrote:

> It is better style for everything to return to main and let it handle exiting.

So that answers that, also thanks everyone for the pointers of `sys.exit()` vs `exit()`