# Why shouldn't I use exit() in Python programs?

Tags: python, exit

According to *[Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6501121/3357935)*, the preferred way to exit from a Python application is to use `sys.exit()`. [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#quit) states that `exit()` should only be used to exit from the interactive shell.

> The [`site`](https://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site) module (which is imported automatically during startup,
>   except if the [`-S`](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#id3) command-line option is given) adds several constants
>   to the built-in namespace. **They are useful for the interactive
>   interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.**

While the documentation warns against using constants from the `site` module, it doesn't explain *why* we shouldn't use them.

**Why shouldn't `exit()` be used in Python applications?**

Comment: This answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501134/5267751).

Comment: Because... it's not _intended_ to be used.

Comment: @AdrianoSilva &  user202729 - The OP has already linked that question

Comment: Sorry. The correct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747557/803316

Answer (score 2):

The `site` module, which is responsible for injecting `exit()` and other things into global scope for convenience in the REPL, is not guaranteed to be loaded.  If you rely on it, and it's not there, your app will break unexpectedly.

Just to be safe, `from sys import exit` will do you no harm.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better practice to use `sys.exit()` instead of importing `exit()`?

Comment: There's no difference.