# Calling exit() as a global function causes KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a module manager for a program that I am writing now, and I wanted to store the module names in a dictionary then reference them and call them from `globals()`.

```
module_number = 5
module_names  = ["", "quiz", "scores", "gender", "help", "exit"]
```

I would then expect that I can call

```
globals()[module_names[module_number]]()
```

Which would call `exit()` and close the script, instead I get the resulting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "a2.py", line 103, in  start() File "a2.py", line 44, in start menu() File "a2.py", line 36, in menu call_module(choice) File "a2.py", line 50, in call_module globals()converter[int(module_number)]
>
> **KeyError: 'exit'**

Comment: [Difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6501121/674039)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit` isn't in `globals()` because it isn't a global, it's a builtin.

In Python, the "global" namespace is per-module, not system-wide. There's a special "builtins" module that holds the things that are truly system-wide, like [the normal builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and a few special things like `exit`.

---

You can access this module with [`import builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

The way the interpreter accesses this module is a little funky. Global lookup works roughly like this:

```
def get_global(global_namespace, name):
    try:
        return global_namespace[name]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    try:
        builtins = global_namespace['__builtins__']
    except KeyError:
        raise NameError(name)
    if isinstance(builtins, types.ModuleType):
        builtins = builtins.__dict__
    try:
        return builtins[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise NameError(name)
```

There's special code in places like [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), and the internal code for building function objects, that makes sure that if you override the normal `globals` dictionary, `__builtins__` gets copied over (unless you explicitly tell it not to). When the import system builds a module object out of your module source (or compiled `.pyc`), it calls `exec`, so every module's globals ends up with the right `__builtins__`.

---

Most things in the `builtins` module are there because they're compiled into it (as you'd expect from the name); for CPython, you can see the source in [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c).

But notice that `exit` isn't there. In fact, it's injected into the `builtins` module by the [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) module, which is imported (unless you disable it) as part of the normal startup sequence. You can see the code that does this in [`Lib/site.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/site.py#L353) and [`Lib/_sitebuiltins.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L13). And the [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) constant says it's injected this way.

---

So, when you type `exit` in your code, or at the interactive prompt, it's found in `globals()['__builtins__']['exit']` or `globals()['__builtins__'].__dict__['exit']`.

But if you want to access it manually, you're better off doing an `import builtins` and accessed it as `builtins.exit`.

Although really, you rarely want to access `builtins.exit` anyway; if you want to exit programmatically, call [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), which is a normal function. `builtins.exit` is a special `Quitter` object that's made specifically for interactive use. (It has a `repr` that gives a helpful message if you forget the parentheses, and some extra code to make it play nice with IDLE.)

In fact, the docs on the [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) constant explicitly say that it's:

> … useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.

Comment: -1 exit is not really in the builtins.  it's injected by site.  if you run `python -S` to disable site, you'll find that exit is not there..

Comment: @wim It _is_ in `builtins`. The fact that it's injected there, rather than being part of `bltinmodule.c`, doesn't change that fact. But if you think my answer isn't long enough, I can always add even more information…

Comment: "it's a builtin" is misleading or glossing over -  it's an instance of [`Quitter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80b762f010097ab8137782e5fbdc89c5c620ed4e/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L13-L26) patched in by site.  Kind of different than being a built-in IMO.

Comment: @wim I don't think it's at all misleading. It's a callable object in `builtins`. And I already differentiated it from "the normal builtin functions" in the first paragraph, and explained how it's not just a function at the end. But to make you happy, I added a section about how it ends up in `builtins` (at least in CPython and PyPy).

Comment: @wim Also, would you say that, e.g., `SyntaxError` isn't built in because in Python 3 the builtin exceptions are injected into `builtin`, not compiled into the module?

Comment: Not really, those are documented as "Built-in Exceptions", and as far as I know it's not possible to import builtins module without binding them.  `exit`, `copyright`, etc are just documented as "constants added by the site module". There are other modules that also monkeypatch built-ins (for example IPython adds/modifies a few names), or you could patch your own in `sitecustomize.py` - it wouldn't elevate those objects to the status of "it's a builtin" just because the builtins module namespace is writable.