# How do I stop a program when the user types "No"?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a complete newbie and was trying to make a number magic trick. I want the program to stop when the user types "No". Here is my code below!

```
 print("Hello and welcome to the number magic trick!!")
x = input("Yes or No")
if x == "Yes":
    print("Yay!!")
    print("Pick an integer number from 1 to 10 but don't tell me!")
    print("Multiply this number with 2")
    print("Multiply the new number by 5")
    print("Now, divide your current number with your original number")
    print("Subtract 7 from your current number")
    print("Is the answer 3 ?")
elif x == "No":
    print("Boo!!")
else:
    print("Invalid Input")

y = input ("Yes or No")
if y  == "Yes":
    print("Cool isn't it?")
elif y == "No":
    print("You can't do math!")
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: I always write functions and call the function at the end of the script (if __name__ == "__main__": ). That way you just use return.

Comment: @SimonHobbs This isn't necessarily good practice. See my answer below for details...

Comment: This method leads to more general, reusable code and avoids exception call overhead. Why is it bad practice?

Comment: @SimonHobbs I didn't say it was bad practice. Just that it can sometimes be so... It can be very helpful in several circumstances!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to raise an error, you could simply use the `exit` method instead:

```
if x.strip().lower() == "no":
  print("You said no!")
  exit(0)
```

You could even use the `exit` method from the `sys` module, like this:

```
import sys

if x.strip().lower() == "no":
  print("You said no!")
  sys.exit(0)
```

**INFO:** The `0` in the `exit` method's parenthesis means that *"this program finished without any errors"* but replacing the `0` with a `1` would mean that *"something went wrong with the program"* and it's exiting with an error.

Good luck.

Comment: What's the difference between the two `exit()` methods?

Comment: [`exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#exit) is a helper for the interactive shell, [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is intended for use in programs. You can find out more about the differences from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501134/10415695).

Answer (score 1):

You could **raise an exception.** Also, it's good practice to put one-line if/else statements on the same line... For example,

```
print("Hello and welcome to the number magic trick!!")
x = input("Yes or No")
if x == "Yes":
    print("Yay!!")
    print("Pick an integer number from 1 to 10 but don't tell me!")
    print("Multiply this number with 2")
    print("Multiply the new number by 5")
    print("Now, divide your current number with your original number")
    print("Subtract 7 from your current number")
    print("Is the answer 3 ?")
elif x == "No":
    print("Boo!!")
    raise SystemExit()
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
    raise SystemExit()

y = input ("Yes or No")
if y  == "Yes":
    print("Cool isn't it?")
elif y == "No":
    print("You can't do math!")
    raise SystemExit()
else:
    print("Invalid input")
    raise SystemExit()
```

You're welcome to use this code...

Answer (score 1):

```
if x == "No":
     quit()
```

## OR

```
from sys import exit 
if x == "No":
     exit()
```