# Why can't I close when using pystray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, pystray

I've written a program using tkinter which when the main window is closed is supposed to be minimized to the system tray. But when I try to exit the program clicking "Close" in the tray that triggers the following function:

```
def quit_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop() # Удаление иконки из трея
    sys.exit(0) # Завершение программы
```

But it does not work and throws the following exception:

```
An error occurred when calling message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 386, in _dispatcher
    return int(icon._message_handlers.get(
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 207, in _on_notify 
    descriptors[index - 1](self)
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 267, in inner
    callback(self)
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 368, in __call__
    return self._action(icon, self)
  File "c:/Users/a-par/mini_library_2020/LC.pyw", line 2976, in quit_window
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
```

Also there's a VK bot in the program which is supposed to work when the program is minimized (it's the reason for actually minimizing to the tray). The bot works in a different from GUI thread. I tried to delete the bot fully but it didn't any help. Maybe the problem is threads but I don't think that way...

### Minimally reproducible non-working code:

```
import pystray
import sys
import time
from PIL import Image
from pystray import Menu, MenuItem


def exit_action(icon):
    sys.exit(0)


def setup(icon):
    icon.visible = True
    
    i = 0
    while icon.visible:
        # Some payload code
        print(i)
        i += 1
        
        time.sleep(5)


def init_icon():
    icon = pystray.Icon('mon')
    icon.menu = Menu(
        MenuItem('Exit', lambda : exit_action(icon)),
    )
    icon.icon = Image.open('C:/Users/a-par/mini_library_2020/logo.ico')
    icon.title = 'tooltip'

    icon.run(setup)

init_icon()
```

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XOulAT_588u_aK4iVvTzoRV_lsPCh06/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well instead of `sys.exit(0)`, I use `exit()`. To read more about the difference read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python). Also the error is just telling you that that function wants to close the program. Nothing more

Comment: @TheLizzard, I understand, but it doesn't let you close the program. Because of this, the function does not work as it should. Also, when `exit()` displays an error, but instead of `0`, the value is `None`

Comment: I think you should ignore the error because technically each time you close any python program it raises an error and that is how it closes.

Comment: I would be happy, but only she continues to hang between two "worlds" and loads the system

Comment: I am not that familiar with how `pystray` works but can you just set a global variable and when the variable is `True` you call `exit()` outside of that function? If that doesn't work I am, out of ideas

Comment: @TheLizzard, Tried an idea like this, didn't help

Answer (score 2):

`sys.exit()` will not work as it is not executed from the main thread or something.
You need to use `icon.stop()` to close the event loop of pystray, thereby stopping the entire program.

Comment: icon.stop() doesn't works when setup parameter is provided to the 'run' method.