# check list of return value from python script in bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash

Is there a way to get the list of return values from python script in the bash script?
Tried:

test_python_return_list.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "check return list from python"
out=($(python3 ./test_return_list.py))

echo "return from python script: "
echo $(out)
```

test_return_list.py:

```
ret = [1, 2, 3]
exit(ret)
```

Test result:

```
$./test_python_return_list.sh
check return list from python
[1,2,3]                      --> why/where this printout is from?
return from python script: 
                             ---> echo $(out) print out nothing, how do I get the [1,2,3] in the bash script?
$
```

Thanks!

Comment: A couple points. (1) `sys.exit()` should be used instead of `exit()`, the latter is [for humans while the former is for programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python). (2) Anything passed to `sys.exit` is printed to standard error.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues with the current code:

- invalid shebang (missing leading `/`)
- `echo $(out)` should be generating an error that `out` is an invalid command unless ... a) OP does in fact have a command named `out` or b) code displayed in question is different than OP's actual script; regardless, `out` is being populated as an array so need a different syntax to display
- the `python/exit(ret)` command appears to send its ouput to stderr, but the `out=(...)` call is only capturing stdout

re: `python/exit(ret)` result:

```
$ python3 ./test_return_list.py > py.stdout 2>py.stderr
==> py.stderr <==
[1, 2, 3]

==> py.stdout <==
                         # empty file
```

Making a few changes to OP's current `bash` script:

```
$ cat test_python_return_list.sh
#!/bin/bash                                         # fix shebang

echo "check return list from python"
out=( $(python3 ./test_return_list.py 2>&1) )       # redirect stderr to stdout

echo "return from python script: "
echo "${out[@]}"                                    # echo contents of array out[]
typeset -p out                                      # alternative display of out[] contents
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./test_python_return_list.sh
check return list from python
return from python script:
[1, 2, 3]
declare -a out=([0]="[1," [1]="2," [2]="3]")
```

**NOTE:** while this should address the syntax issues I can't speak to whether or not this is OP's expected contents of the `out[]` array ...

Comment: By the way,  do you know how to distinguish between list return and single value?
Thanks.

Comment: @issac I'm not sure I understand the question; in this particular case python is returning a string `[1, 2, 3]` which `bash` processes as 3 separate strings `[1,` / `2,` / `3]`; if your intention is to return something different then I'd suggest experimenting with what you assign to `ret` and if you're unable to come up with the desired solution then consider asking a new question that focuses on the issue of how to return `XXX` to `bash`