# No "nohup" python command results

Tags: python, linux, ssh, bluehost

I'm developing a real time website. It's a map where the color of each city changes based on the current emotion.

I have the python part which is connected to my database.
So whenever I run the python code a new record is added to the database. - it's a streaming code so it's never ending.

The command line that is suitable for my python code is (nohup) since I want it always running.

I'm using (Bluehost) as hosting server - VPS package.

I opened my SSH command line and run the command:
[image]

So this means it's working? It created an out file
but no record is added to the database!

What's the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Please post plain text instead of an image, especially when the image has such poor contrast.

Comment: open the `nohup.out` file you have errors in your python code

Comment: But why when I run the code I have no problem but with nohup it occurs?

Comment: `nohup` redirects `stdin` to an unreadable file and `stdout` to `nohup.out`. If your python script needs stdin, that will certainly cause problems. What is in the output?

Comment: I tried to run the command so I can get to see what is in "nohup.out". But it isn't creating the file.

Comment: This is what I got (root@server.x.mybluehost.me [public_html]# nohup python streamTweets.js &
[1] 2547
root@server.x.mybluehost.me [public_html]# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out')_

Answer (score 3):

The line `Exit 2` means that there is a problem. You'll find a description in `nohup.out` (see the line that says `ignoring input and appending nohup.out`)

For a hint more clarity: the line that has `Exit ...` means the process called through nohup has terminated. The integer generally has meaning ([more on those here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285289/exit-codes-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), but you need to look at the actual `nohup.out` file before you'll learn anything.

Comment: Should I be able to open? Because it won't let me

Comment: Have you tried chmodding it? You should be the owner.

Comment: I deleted the previous file and tried to run the command again but this is what I got: ((root@server.x.mybluehost.me [public_html]# nohup python streamTweets.js &
[1] 2547
root@server.x.mybluehost.me [public_html]# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'))