# Repeat counter when index ends

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, counter

Simple question - I want a loop that counts up and returns to 0 when it reaches a certain number.

Tried something like:

```
while i < 7:
    i += 1
    if i == 7
        i -= 1   #(or change i in any other way - you get the idea)
```

My Python actually crashed when I tried the above.

EDIT: Yes, the `if` condition is never met - it still crashes when I change it to `if i == 6` though.

Comment: What do you mean by return? Directly return to 0 or decrement to zero?

Comment: Change `i -= 1` to `return 0`.

Comment: [`for i in itertools.cycle(range(7)):`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)?

Comment: it doesnt really matter if its decrementing or returning - i just cant find a way to change a variable if a while loop ends

Comment: @jordanm
{
        while i < 7:
            i += 1
            return 0
}
gives me a syntax error ("'return' outside function")

Comment: You are missing the colon after `if i == 7`.

Comment: If you want to re-run the loop multiple times you have to put it in a loop. Or write it in such a way that it never ends in the first place.

Comment: With the colon, the code looks fine. You are going to have to be more specific about the error you are receiving. @jonrsharpe's suggestion would be the preferred way to write this, though.

Comment: `if i == 6: i = 0`

Comment: Why not leave the IF out and just st set i=0 after loop exits?

Comment: the crash is not the issue here - i just want the counter to end at the maximum array lenght and then go back to 0.

Comment: Do you want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,... or 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,... ?

Comment: it really doesnt matter as i said - i just want to generally know HOW to any of this, so an example on any of those two would do

Comment: Well, if it does not matter, then either you really just have a typo (missing `:`) or the question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while i < 7:
      i += 1
      if i == 7:
         i = 0
```

The problem is the i-=1 line. Your code works as i counts up to 6, but when it reaches 6, it is incremented to 7, and then subtracted down to 6 again. Your current sequence is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,...

Comment: still crashes though :/

Comment: You haven't specified a reason for the program to stop, so it should loop infinitely. You need an exit condition.

Comment: i thought that the above "for" loop i used makes it finite - i am using the turtle module and want to change the color after each square until it drew 36 squares

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count up to 7 then count down to 0 here is what you can try:

```
i = 0
add = True
while True:
    if add:
        i += 1
    else:
        i -= 1

    if i in [0, 7]:
        add = not add
```

Comment: tells me that "name 'true' is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, the booleans value for python are "True" and "False". I'll edit the answer and improve the code quality

Comment: ah, totally forgot that its case sensitive

Comment: You could also try something like `if i in (0, 7): increment *= -1`

Comment: still crashes. this is a tough one

Comment: @FlyingThunder No, it is not. It is just _very_ unclear what "crashes" means. I assume that it does not actually freeze your computer or similar. Does the program terminate with an exception? If so, _which exception_?

Comment: Maybe because this is an inifity loop. You should avoid it with a "End controll"

Comment: Python not responding (Backend terminated (returncode: 3489660927))

Comment: instead of "while True" use a counter to stop the iteration and increment its value into "if i in [0,7]" statement

Answer (score 0):

This is your corrected code,

```
i = 0
while i < 7:
    i += 1
    if i == 6:
           i = 0
```

It reaches 0 on reaching 6.
Lot's of syntax Error fixed.

Comment: the moment i added this python started crashing again

Comment: Python not responding (Backend terminated (returncode: 3489660927))

Comment: @FlyingThunder Go to this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285289/exit-codes-in-python