# Python Can't load .txt file

Tags: python

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1JCl.jpg)
This code can't load the `log.txt` file.
The file is in the `temp` folder.
Why can't I load it?
This code only displays the text: `Search word: ABC`.

```
text = input("Search word: ABC")
with open("C:\Temp\log.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    cnt = 0
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split()
        if (l[-1] == text):
            print(line.strip())
            cnt += 1
    if (cnt): print(cnt, "count")
    else: print(text, "No data.")
```

Comment: Please include any errors or return codes as it is very hard to understand what is failing without them

Comment: There is no error.
Just if I type ABC, This code need to find and print the ABC in txt, but it's not

Comment: Is there a return code or does the application hang?

Comment: No hang. What does the return code mean?

Comment: It is the status when your Python application finishes running (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/285289/323177 for more details). Can you share how you are running this program (e.g. the command line or IDE) and screenshots/text shown?

Comment: Added picture to content.
If press Run, it is still running without shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to type the word after running the program. The "ABC" you see is the prompt from the script i.e. it is not entered by you. That's why the program keeps running, waiting for the input and doesn't go further.

Here's your code slightly modified to make it clear.

```
text = input("Search word: ")
with open("C:\Temp\log.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    cnt = 0
    for line in f:
        if text in line:
            print(line.strip())
            cnt += 1
    if cnt:
        print(cnt, "count")
    else:
        print(text, "No data.")
```

Comment: I misunderstood the code. Your help was great.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you understand that your code:

- ask the user to input some *text*
- count the occurrences of that *text* in the file `C:\Temp\log.txt`, under the conditions:

  - the *text* does not contains space
  - the *text* is at the end of the line
  - the *text* may be followed by one or more spaces
  - the *text* must be preceded by one or more spaces
  - the file cannot have empty lines

Under those conditions, your code should behave nicely. I would recommend to change `text = input("Search word: ABC")` to `text = input("Search word: ")` to make it clear that the user need to input some text.

If you still have unexpected results, check if you don't have any character encoding issue (like a terminal default encoding not being utf-8)

Comment: I misunderstood the code. Your help was great.
Thank you very much.