# how do i get dockerfile to return a specific exit code from my program

Tags: docker, file

how do i get dockerfile to return a specific exit code from my program?
I have a python program and would like to return a code of 2 under certain conditions.

Simply using return 2 does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See [mcve] for how to provide a more complete question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive exit code from your program that runs in container you could use docker [inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) command:

```sh
docker inspect --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}' $INSTANCE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will give that a try if replacing return 2 with sys.exit(2) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Return(2) vs sys.exit(2) is the issue.

The issue was uncovered in this post.

[Exit codes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285289/exit-codes-in-python)